# Find/replace texts in Word document footer using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word, footer

I want to replace some tags in my Word document. My current solution does not implement the replacement/search at the document footer.

The word template I am using has 2 different footers (first page is different to second page footer). I want to change something in the footer of the second page.

```
'replacement regarding CHAPTER 1
For CurRow = Tabelle2.Range("C2") To Tabelle2.Range("C3")
    If Tabelle2.Range("B" & CurRow).Value = "x" Then
        ReplacementTextF = "<<TagToBeFound>>"
        ReplacementText = "I am a customer"
        dataObjectLongText.SetText ReplacementText
        dataObjectLongText.PutInClipboard       'Copy to clipboard
        With WordDoc.Content.Find
            .Execute FindText:=ReplacementTextF, ReplaceWith:="^c", Replace:=2, Wrap:=wdFindContinue    'Paste from clipboard
        End With
```

Until here, everything works as it should. It finds all texts and replace them using the clipboard (because the replacement text is often greater than 255 characters).

To take a look into the footer I tried this right after the code above:

```
        With WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.Find
            .Execute FindText:=ReplacementTextF, ReplaceWith:="^c", Replace:=2, Wrap:=wdFindContinue    'Paste from clipboard
        End With
```

I tried several solutions. This is my last approach. I referenced the Word object library.

Comment: May you have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33233357/1306012

Comment: @user1651460 As you're now saying you've referenced the Word object library, you can use the named constants throughout - see the code I posted for the details. My comments regarding the STYLEREF field remain pertinent, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears you're using late binding, you can't simply employ a Word constant like wdFindContinue; you need to either declare it or use its numerical equivalent. Other complications can arise if a previous Find/Replace used wildcards and/or formatting for the Find or Replace arguments, so it's wise to reset these. Try:

```
With WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.Find '1 = wdHeaderFooterPrimary
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = ReplacementTextF
  .Replacement.Text = "^c"    'Paste from clipboard
  .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Execute Replace:=2 'wdReplaceAll
End With
```

or:

```
With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(9).Find '9 = wdPrimaryFooterStory
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = ReplacementTextF
  .Replacement.Text = "^c"    'Paste from clipboard
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
  .Execute Replace:=2 'wdReplaceAll
End With
```

In any event, since it appears the footer is to display the same content as you're replacing ReplacementTextF in the document body with, you might do better to assign a unique Style name to whatever ReplacementTextF is, then reference that Style via a STYLEREF field in the footer. Do this in the template. That way, you'd obviate the need for a Find/Replace in the footer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were absolutly right in the first part! The second I do not (yet) understand it clearly. Might need some more quite minutes for that. But for now I will work with the first code solution of your answer as it satisfy my needs.